# How to Stop Poly-Line Creation in This Code?

Tags: jquery

How can I update this code to only draw lines between two click events? I mean How I can set a new start point for a new pair of clicks and stop creation a Poly-line? Can you please also help me to keep the line inside a Mouse-down and -Up event instead of Click events?

**[Here is the Web Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/cKxnw/)**

and Here is the code

```
var needFirstPoint = true;
function drawNextLine(ctx, x, y) {
if (needFirstPoint) {
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    needFirstPoint = false;
}
else {
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.stroke();
}
 }
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var canvas = $('#myCanvas').get(0);
  if (!canvas.getContext) { return; }
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  $('#myCanvas').on('click', function(e){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var x = e.pageX - offset.left;
    var y = e.pageY - offset.top;
    drawNextLine(ctx, x, y);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not super fluid so you may need to play with it more but this worked for me:

```
else {
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.stroke();
    needFirstPoint = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I once wrote a similar function for http://www.kolchose.org/simon/ajaximagemapcreator/ and i used double click to stop the drawing of the canvas.